# Purpose of Secure Key in Facebook(and other provider) in OAUTH?

Tags: oauth, facebook

I see lot of OAUTH provider give us a secure key. What is the purpose of secure key in Facebook(and other provider) in OAUTH?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand? You could refer to individual pages or sections in the [FB developer guides](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/)

Comment: @scuzzy-delta, in short what is the purpose of secure  key